# Is a full stack developer job worth the stress/effort? (Full stack vs backend vs CTO vs entrepreneur)

Tags: software-industry, software-development, startup

Considering the fact that a full stack developer needs to have strong skills for devops, backend, front end, business modeling, networking, infrastructure, basically strong skills for the whole stack, why should a skilled developer hunt for these kind of jobs and not hunt for a CTO/IT management type of position (which is usually better paid)?

Why should't a skilled full stack developer not open his own workshop and work directly for clients / startups (since startup companies are usually looking for these kind of devs).

Why shouldn't a full stack developer focus on a backend/frontend only job (less stress, alot of extra time to focus on other things) and get 20-30% less pay?

Is the full stack dev job worth the effort compared to other oportunities?

I am asking this because lately I've seen a boom on the job market for full stack devs and after some research, it seems that the pay is not far greater than the one a focused/backend/frontend dev would get (compared to CTOs that usually even get equity and far greater pay).

Comment: Why would someone who wants to do development take a management role? Why would someone who wants a reliable paycheck without client interaction get into freelancing? Why do you say a full stack role is more stressful / effort? Why do you care what other people think instead of just doing what you want to do?

Comment: @Dukeling I was asking for advice. When building your career it's not always about what you like to do, it's also about what needs to be done, what path to follow to have a better life. So I asked if following the full stack dev path in a company is worth trying compared to the others. I actually tried both entrpreneur (full stack) and in a company (not for long) and was wondering now agian to try a full time job or go all in with employees maybe for the entrpreneur route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it more as a preference. If you like UIs, responsiveness, and stylesheets then you would do frontend. If you prefer APIs, restful services and traditional programming then you would do (web) backend. If you like both, you would do web fullstack. Things get hairy when Backend means different things for different people. It might be cloud config, setting up event workflows and databases and have almost zero programming.

Comment: Full stack means alot more than frontend / backend coding. It means docker, it means consul, it means services orchestration, it means networking, it means scalability, it means design, security, testing , business modeling etc. I've seen job offerings where they were looking for a jack of all trades (full stack dev) which included as requirements many of the above. So I was wondering if there is any real benefit to hunt these jobs since they are a hot trend now. Because to me, it seems like they are asking too many and maybe not offering that much in return

Comment: P.S. I've been working on startups and was wondering what is the tradeoff to work directly on startups for clients or get hired by a company who requires the skills to pass along projects from clients (at least this is what they seem to do when I see so many requirements and probably little more pay than a specialized dev since they need to get some proffit)

Comment: @GeoC. You wouldn't (or shouldn't) have such a wide range of responsibilities at a typical (development-focused) large company, full-stack or not. Big companies hire testers, designers, security experts, whomever does business modelling and network engineers as separate roles from developers. Small companies don't have the budget or amount of work for all of that, so employees often need to do a wide range of things.

Comment: Service design, networking (if you mean data?), and security are generally more in the ballpark of architects or possibly a separate devops team, at least from my experience in small, medium and huge corporations.

Comment: @Dukeling True , one should not have such a wide range of responsibilities, but it seems that some companies (mostly small) require these things in their job offerings. This is why I was wondering if there is any benefit in accepting any of these jobs. But in the end probably I will exclude these kind of companies from deciding my path. The return / effort ratio can be smaller than if one would go the entrepreneur route.

Comment: @GeoC. I don't see jobs as having some objective return / effort ratio, but I rather try to find jobs that excite me personally. When you look at it that way, it's much easier to figure out whether or not you want some job.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen When you work on startups you kind of have to do it all. Not to mention that some startups ask for "all in". What I think is some small companies ask for many skills because 1. they can't affoard many devs, 2. they don't have the age and knowledge to be organized, 3. they IT business is booming and people just went into it without the knowhow and depend on devs to do the things. So I was wondering, if anybody worked in such companies and if it's worth the effort/knowledge.

Comment: @Dukeling I guess I like to get something in return for my effort, I can't just work for pleasure/passion. Some people will just use others if they are not careful. Generally from my point of view it's good to think about what you get in return for your effort. For example entrepreneurs who simply hire full stack devs , develop startup products (software) at low cost and profit (millions sometimes). What is worth millions? The idea or the knowhow? I think both, but in too many cases the first one wins.

Comment: @GeoC. Yes, money matters too, but this question seems to be disregarding your own pleasure *completely*. It's about like asking whether it's better to be a doctor or a stock trader - it really depends a lot on how much you care about each one. Know-how is only worth as much as the cost of the next person (or persons) with that knowledge.

Comment: ``So I was wondering, if anybody worked in such companies and if it's worth the effort/knowledge`` Absolutely. I learned more in the ~2 years at a startup than I did in 5 years at a huge corporation and self-studying in my freetime :) The advantage in the startup scene is also that you are not **expected** to know it all. There is ample opportunity to learn new things on the job. Which at least to me is the biggest motivator in any job.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view many companies nowadays look for full stack developers (at least here in Germany), because projects switch fast and today they need a UI developer, but in 6 months there's a project with mainly backend dev tasks.

So while a specialist is still needed, generalists give the companies more flexibility.

CTO or entrepreneur is a whole different scope or skillset than developer, so that's not the alternative for most people.